Ternimal of VSCode
When I start to run code for the second time in VSCode, the terminal seems to appear >> and stops me from inputting or even can't get the program to start.


I see a single unmatched quote '. However, is this about Ubuntu?

I initially closed this as a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/q/179199/380067 however I didn't notice it was a PowerShell prompt, so it should be closed as off-topic; @OP your problem has nothing to do with Ubuntu, the issue you're having is PowerShell related; see here (Here-strings section) and mind this part: "PowerShell allows double- or single-quoted strings to span multiple lines [...]"
